# "Issue with my Trading View Scripting RSI"

Tags: rsi

I would like to ask, how do I solve the following error>

Error at 3:19 Syntax error at input 'rsi'

The script is>

> //@version=5 strategy("VWAP, RSI, and ADX Mean Reversion Strategy",
> overlay=true) // Inputs vwap_length = input(20, "VWAP Length",
> minval=1) rsi_length = input(4, "RSI Length", minval=1) rsi_overbought
> = input(70, "RSI Overbought Level", minval=1) rsi_oversold = input(30, "RSI Oversold Level", minval=1) adx_length = input(14, "ADX Length",
> minval=1) adx_level = input(25, "ADX Level", minval=1) // Calculate
> VWAP and RSI vwap = vwap(hlc3) rsi = rsi(close, rsi_length) //
> Calculate ADX up = change(high) down = -change(low) trur = rma(tr,
> adx_length) plus = fixnan(100 * rma(up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0,
> adx_length) / trur) minus = fixnan(100 * rma(down > up and down > 0 ?
> down : 0, adx_length) / trur) sum = plus + minus adx = 100 *
> rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adx_length) // Plot VWAP
> and RSI plot(vwap, "VWAP", color=color.blue) plot(rsi, "RSI",
> color=color.purple) // Entry and exit conditions longCondition = close
> < vwap and rsi > rsi_overbought and adx < adx_level if longCondition
> strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) shortCondition = close > vwap
> and rsi < rsi_oversold and adx < adx_level if shortCondition
> strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) // Stop loss and take profit
> stopLoss = input(2.0, "Stop Loss %", step=0.1) / 100 takeProfit =
> input(5.0, "Take Profit %", step=0.1) / 100 strategy.exit("Exit Long",
> "Long", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLoss),
> limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfit))
> strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", stop=strategy.position_avg_price
>
> - (1 + stopLoss), limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takeProfit))

My point of view that this script was created for version 4 instead of 5, thus I would like to know what is missing?

Thanks.